# Print starting from match pattern in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script which provides me with results in text form.
I need to print only some information from this text.
How do I define start pattern and end pattern to print in Perl?

Comment: Here is my results :  Current port-limit unlimited Protocol Stack IPV4 ip address  (applied) qos-policing-policy rate-2M-in (applied) qos-metering-policy rate-2M-out (applied) [sCLIPS]Redback(config-ctx)#         and i need to print only   qos-policing-policy rate-2M-in (applied)  qos-metering-policy rate-2M-out (applied)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please edit your question and insert the information from your comment. Also, tell us what output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know exactly what you are asking, but I will make a try. 
Let's say that you are streamimg a file contaning plain text, and you only want to filter out lines containing  "qos-policing-policy rate-2M-in (applied) qos-metering-policy rate-2M-out (applied)" and only extract those words, then following code could give an idea how to write your script:

Perl Program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# test.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>) {
        my @a = m/(qos-\S+\s+\S+\s+\(applied\))/g; 
        for my $i (@a) {
            print "$i ";
        }
        print "\n" if (@a);
}
```

This would be your start pattern and end pattern:

```
m/qos-\S+\s+\S+\s+\(applied\)/g
```

Where start is:

```
qos-
```

and end is:

```
\(applied\)
```

While "g" option is used for global matches on the incoming line.

**Input:**

```
> cat textFile.txt
Current port-limit unlimited Protocol Stack IPV4 ip address (applied) qos-policing-policy rate-2M-in (applied) qos-metering-policy rate-2M-out (applied) [sCLIPS]Redback(config-ctx)
line number two is here
Stack IPV4 ip address (applied) qos-policing-policy rate-299M-in (applied) qos-metering-policy
```

**Output:**

```
> cat textFile.txt | perl ./test.pl
qos-policing-policy rate-2M-in (applied) qos-metering-policy rate-2M-out (applied)
qos-policing-policy rate-299M-in (applied)
```

Comment: my text file is :    Session state Up
        Circuit   3/3 vlan-id 1523
        Internal Circuit   3/3:511:63:31/1/2/20600
        Interface bound  staticip81
        Current port-limit unlimited
        Protocol Stack IPV4
        qos-policing-policy rate-2M-in (applied)
        qos-metering-policy rate-2M-out (applied)
[sCLIPS]Redback(config-ctx)#

Comment: and i need only      qos-policing-policy rate-2M-in (applied) qos-metering-policy rate-2M-out (applied)

Comment: What kind of fault do you get

Comment: Try this one-liner if it works. It works for my: cat yourFile.txt |  perl -ne '@a = m/(qos-\S+\s+\S+\s+\\(applied\\))/g; for $i (@a) {print $a[$i];} print "\n" if(@a);'

Comment: i get Blanc nothing

Comment: yes it worked how do i put this inside the script ... i mean not from the command line

Comment: Here it works with no issue. just print a plain hello somwhere in the script and see if that works first,

Comment: print works fine ... now i need to integrate this command inside my script

Comment: If you think this answer was useful then do not forget to push the arrowbutton "This answer is useful"

Comment: no your solution works in the command line but inside the script it gives me Blanc nothing

Comment: They are exactly the same, exept for usage of strict option. Maybe some formatting issue when you copied the text from stackoverflow. If you look you will see they are exactly the same codewise.

Comment: Did you run it like this: cat yourFile.txt | perl ./test.pl

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;

while(<in.txt>) {
        my @a = m/(qos-\S+\s+\S+\s+\(applied\))/g; for $i (@a) {print $a[$i];} print "\n" if(@a);
}

Comment: i need one script perl

Comment: but it give me nothing

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code posted, I let you troubleshoot your own enviroment. If my post gave some hints on how to state start and end pattern, then you should mark it as useful, which it obviously was since you are going to integrate the pattern into your script.